# How can I allow users of my site to have a personal URL with .net core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, razor-pages

If I have my site at example.com and I have a user called Joe, how can I allow Joe (or anyone else registered on the site) to have a personal/custom URL like example.com/Joe? I'm using Razor Pages .net core 3.1 hosted in Azure with a custom domain.

The directory structure is like:

```
example.com/Users/Index?id=1 could rewrite to example.com/Joe
example.com/Profiles/Index?id=7 could rewrite to example.com/Joe/Profile
example.com/Photos/Index?id=5 could rewrite to example.com/Joe/Photos
```

etc

Comment: I think the structure is like `example.com/Users/:id could rewrite to example.com/Users/Joe`,`example.com/Profiles/:id could rewrite to example.com/Profiles/Joe` and so on.

Comment: @Dobestar, will it be feasible to have user name as friendly as user name can be duplicate how will you handle that case.. How will you handle two users with same name?

Comment: Learning is right, so it is recommended not to use the username on the url, but to use the userid. You can see example:  https://stackoverflow.com/users/7687666

Comment: How is the progress on this issue? Do you need further help?

Comment: If I wanted to let the User choose their personal profile 'name' - which at the time of recording i could check that it's unique - how could I set a rewrite rule to look up that name in a database then redirect to the correct url, e.g. if someone sets their page alias as Bumblebee123, then the url 'Users/Bumblebee123' should check the db, find the record, say it has an Id of 5, then redirect to 'Users/Index?id=5'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use urlrewrite in your project. For more detail you can see [offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-3.1).

[image]

[image]

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
        // add rewrite
        var rewrite = new RewriteOptions()
         .AddRewrite(@"user/(.*)", "home/user?username=$1", skipRemainingRules: true);
        app.UseRewriter(rewrite);

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```